# how to copy files in use with robocopy?

Tags: backup, robocopy, locked-files

I am having a batch file performing some backup operations.
The backup operations look like this:

robocopy %source% %root%\%targetname% /MIR /R:0 /W:0 /NFL /NDL /NJS

Unfortunatly some files in use cannot be copied due to windows "protection".
Is there the possiblity to copy files in use?

I am using windows 10.
The backup included in windows 10 is not flexible enough, i cannot just copy some folders and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#No_open_files)

> Robocopy does not copy open files. Any process may open files for exclusive read access by withholding the `FILE_SHARE_READ` flag during opening. Even Robocopy's *Backup mode* will not touch those files.